# Execution failed for task app validateSigningDebug pangu.keystore not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have git cloned react-native app and now trying to run it on android studio and i get error.

> Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
>
> > Keystore file '/home/emilis/Documents/liv3ly/mobile-react-native/android/app/pangu.keystore'
> > not found for signing config 'debug'.

I found solutions only for debug.keystore but not for pangu.keystore
Any help?